# Как должна выглядеть файловая структура сайта по БЭМ?

Tags: html, css, бэм

Как должна выглядеть файловая структура многостраничного сайта по БЭМ при работе с PUG и SCSS? Ясно, что для каждого блока, элемента и модификатора должна быть своя папка, где хранятся css, js и html, НО просмотрев множество видео на ютубе и прочитав много статей я так и не нашел четкое объяснение, как все должно быть устроено... одни создают папку src, другие app и dist и из-за всего этого я запутался и подзакипела голова. Может ли кто показать пример сайта с правильной файловой структурой?

Comment: Вы пытаетесь найти что общего между теплым, мягким и коричневым. Причем тут БЭМ и PUG с SCSS и структура папок в проекте? Это, как бы, штуки из абсолютно разных технологий, решающих разные задачи.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Структура проекта может содержать папки:

- `bin/` для любых исполняемых скриптов либо откомпилированных модулей, используемых в вашем проекте.
- `build/` для скриптов, необходимых для сборки проекта к состоянию "готово к использованию"
- `dist/` для уже собранных, готовых к использованию модулей (как правило, в git отправляют пустую папку)
- `docs/` для документации к вашему проекту
- `env/` для разных окружений, содержащих разные значения переменных окружений (небольшая тавтология).
- `examples/` для примеров использования вашего проекта
- `integration/` для интеграционных тестов
- `lib/` для кода, который может быть запущен как есть
- `src/` для кода, который требует манипуляций (изменений или компиляции) для своего запуска
- `test/` для всех видов тестов
- `unit/` для модульных тестов
- `vendor/` для библиотек других разработчиков или проектов, необходимых для работы текущего проекта